# How to configure Site URL and Canvas URL

Tags: facebook, url, canvas, redirect

I'm trying to configure my application in facebook but I have a trouble.

My application works through a servlet (http://www.mysite.com:port/myproject/servlet). In the settings of the application I'm setting:

```
Site URL: http://mysite:port/myproject/servlet?

Canvas URL: http://mysite:port/myproject/servlet?
```

This configuration works properly except for one detail. If I access it by its URL "http://apps.facebook.com/myapp" or on my home page (column applications on the left side of the page the user) works correctly. But if new user accesses the application, after clicking the "allow" in permission dialog (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication), the application is redirected to a URL outside of facebook (http://mysite:port/myproject/servlet?) When it should be redirected to http://apps.facebook.com/myapp.

What is the correct configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By which URL does the user get to the Auth dialog?

In the first place he should be redirected to:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=email,read_stream`

and **YOUR_URL** should be http://apps.facebook.com/myapp or anything else you want it to be.

Comment: Well, I tried to pass the value http://apps.facebook.com/myapp in redirect_uri, but I get following error in browser:
"Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options."

When I use the value http://mysite:port/myproject/servlet? in redirect_uri the error does not occur, but the redirect occurs to the wrong place.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options, they suggest adding a header there that will fix that. What happens if you omit the redirect_uri at all. By default you should be redirected to the http://apps.facebook.com/myapp. P.S. Wild guess, maybe this has something to do with you not using a standart port (!=80)

Comment: In my servlet I added the following command:
httpServletResponse.addHeader("X-FRAME-OPTIONS", "SAMEORIGIN" );

But not worked.

There another way?